# Zoomable full HD camera registered as a webcam

Tags: windows, webcam, video-streaming, conferencing, gotomeeting

We're using GoToMeeting for online meetings and would like to have a movable, zoomable camera (HD-ready or full HD) connected to it. According to what the guys at GoToMeeting told us, the camera would have to register as a webcam. So my question is: is there any way I could buy a standard video camera and connect it to Windows as a webcam so that GoToMeeting can use it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not with most cameras unless it comes with a driver. In Windows, webcams need a driver to interface between the camera hardware, USB, and the webcam libraries.

Having said that, in the past I did have an expensive video camera that had a FireWire interface for which there were drivers that did this.

Comment: Whats "expensive"?

Comment: It was around UKP1,000 at the time. It had both in and out video feeds and would do transcoding. There was a generic Windows DV (digital video) driver that enabled access to the live video via Firewire. We are going back at least 11 years, it was a Sony.